# Enable Version Control Integration by default on New Project creation in CLion

Tags: git, intellij-idea, clion, jetbrains-ide, gpg-agent

On macOS CLion `File > New > Project`, I want the new project to automatically `VCS > Enable Version Control Integration...`.

Default settings are typically configured with `File > New Projects Setup > Preferences for New Projects...` but I do not see the option there.

I know this is trivial to do by hand, my real issue is I want my GPG key to be configured automatically, and that option is greyed out in `Preferences for New Projects...`, presumably because VCS hasn't been enabled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the IDE wants at least 1 Git root to be present in a project. And you cannot define Git roots (`Directory Mappings` screen) in default settings...

[image]
*(The screenshot is from PhpStorm but it's the same for all IDEA-based IDEs)*

This ticket comment says the same: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-276720#focus=Comments-27-5142532.0-0

> The option is enabled in the context of projects that have Git mappings. Please open a project that has a git repository, and the option will be there.
> **It can not be configured via Preferences for New projects.**

Possible solution:

> However, you could setup gpg in global git config to make it work in all your git projects.